# Outer join in Linq - type interface failed in the call to 'SelectMany'

Tags: c#, linq, left-join, outer-join

I am trying to write a complex query in Linq. I have 6 tabes.

```
Contract (Zero/One to Many) Agent (PK AgentID)
Contract (Zero/One to Many) Customer (PK CustomerID)
Contract (Zero/One to Many) Site (PK SiteID)
Contract (Zero/One to Many) Supplier (PK SupplierID)
Contract (Zero/One to Many) Employee (PK EmployeeID)
```

I need to write a query which returns all contracts even if any of these foreign key is null.

I am not sure whether to use left outer join or right outer join. I know with left outer join we can retrieve all master rows even if there is no child record. I am trying the opposite. I wrote the below query

```
var contracts1 = (from c in ctx.Contracts
join a in ctx.Agents on c.AgentID equals a.AgentID into ca
from a in ca.DefaultIfEmpty
join cu in ctx.Customers on c.CustomerID equals cu.CustomerID into ccu
from cu in ccu.DefaultIfEmpty
join su in ctx.Suppliers on c.SupplierID equals su.SupplierID into csu
from su in csu.DefaultIfEmpty
join s in ctx.Sites on c.SiteID equals s.SiteID into cs
from s in cs.DefaultIfEmpty
join e1 in ctx.employees on c.EmployeeID equals e1.EmployeeID into ce1
from e1 in ce1.DefaultIfEmpty
select new { c, a, cu, su, s, e1 });
```

It does not compile. The error message is 'type interface failed in the call to 'SelectMany'.

I was trying something very simple

```
from a in ctx.Agents
from c in a.Contracts.DefaultIfEmpty
select new { c, a }
```

It works fine without 'DefaultIfEmpty'.

I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: Is this Entity Framework?  If so, why don't you just use the [navigation properties](https://coding.abel.nu/2012/06/dont-use-linqs-join-navigate/) that should have been created?

Comment: Type *inference*. You probably compare nullable types and non-nullable types. But again, you should use navigation properties. If the associations aren't required they will translate to outer joins. No need to do `DefaultIfEmpty()`.

Comment: @juharr I can. But I wasn't sure how to join multiple tables. Is it something like this.. from a in ctx.Agents
                             from c1 in a.Contracts
                             from cu in ctx.Customers
                             from c2 in cu.Contracts
                              from sup in ctx.Suppliers
                              from c3 in sup.Contracts
                              from s in ctx.Sites
                              from c4 in cu.Contracts
                              from e1 in ctx.employees
                              from c5 in e1.Contracts

Comment: @Gert Arnold Is there any way to resolve the type conversion within the query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `DefaultIfEmpty()` in the query, not just `DefaultIfEmtpy`.

Comment: You are a genius. It compiled, let me check what it returns. I will get back to you. Thanks.